# NBuilder parameterless constructor error

Tags: c#, nbuilder

We are using **NBuilder** for generating test data for our tests. We have a few models with private setters. So setting thos properties is only possible throughout the constructor. The problem is that we get the following error from **NBuilder**:

> CompanyAddressViewModel does not have a default parameterless constructor

I understand the error. Do I really need to create a default constructor in my class?

Here is my NBuilder code:

```
Builder<CompanyAddressViewModel>.CreateNew().Build()
```

Comment: Same issue. For example Newtonsoft.Json is able to instantiate classes without default constructors. This feature would be really helpful in NBuilder too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use WithConstructor() or WithFactory() method, in Net Core 2.1 WithConstructor() method is deprecated.

`Builder<CompanyAddressViewModel>.CreateNew(). WithFactory (() => new parameter()).Build()`

Answer (score 1):

Former versions uses `WithConstructor()` method, but it's obsolete in these days, so you should use `WithFactory()` method:

```
Builder<CompanyAddressViewModel>
         .CreateNew()
         .WithFactory(() => new CompanyAddressViewModel("your", "parameter"))
         .Build()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use With method.

```
Builder<CompanyAddressViewModel>
               .CreateNew()
               .With(() => new CompanyAddressViewModel(...))
               .Build()
```